# CRM 2011 - Dynamically Changing Forms ISSUE - JS Error (cannot execute code ...)

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

In the onload of the form I check which type the form has and based on that I load the correct form.  That works but when the form reloads to the new Form I'm getting the following "JavaScript"-error => Kan programmacode niet uitvoeren vanuit een vrijgegeven script (**cannot execute code from freed script** in English I guess).

The code I'm using is the following :

```
avento_customertypecodeChange = function () {
    var lblShow = "information";
    var picklistName = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("customertypecode").getSelectedOption().text.toLowerCase();
    if (picklistName.contains("hc")) {
        lblShow = "information hc";
    }
    else {
        lblShow = "information";
    }

    var newIndex = -1;

    var currentName = Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.getCurrentItem().getLabel().toLowerCase();
    if (currentName != lblShow) {
        Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.items.forEach(function (item, index) {
            var itemLabel = item.getLabel().toLowerCase();
            if (itemLabel == lblShow) {
                newIndex = index;
            }
        });
    }

    if (newIndex != -1) Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.items.get(newIndex).navigate();
}
```

Both forms refer to the same "JavaScript" file.  Is that the problem?  How's the best way to achieve this without having this error?  I'm searching for hours on this and I haven't found a good solution and I'm still having that annoying error!  I'm hoping that you guys have encountered that problem and are able to help me.

Comment: Not sure I quite understand the error message. If your in IE press F12 to get developer tools open and debug the javascipt under the script tab. It could probably help you isolate what's going wrong. If i had to guess, does your form your navigating too also execute the same code, if so does it have the form customer type field??

Comment: Yes it uses the same "JS"-webresource and it has the "Customer Type Field".  Both forms works correctly when you open them seperately.  It's just the dynamic switching that creates the error.  If I change the form on the normal way by changing it with the "Dropdownlist" I'm not getting the error...

Comment: The problem itself is that it should reload the whole page when we've navigated to another form. I don't know how microsoft themselves where abel to navigate to another form when they change from form in the Picklist with the available forms...

Comment: Can you poste the rest of your javascript web resource, is there anything else firing on load?

Comment: Yes there're numerous functions that needs to be executed in the onload.  The first function I tried to execute is the "Form"-changing function.  But that didn't work, so I tried to put it in a timeout, but it still gave the same error. When I only put the "Form"-changing function in the avento_formOnload, it also gave me the error (the one you can click on "send error report" or "don't send"). The function I call on onload is the following : avento_formOnload = function () { ... functions ...  }

Comment: Do you define the 'contains' method on the string prototype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using several tricks, but it's unsupported :

1. I write the new "FormID" to the DB
2. I refresh the complete page
3. The page remembers what FormID it was and opens the correct Form

Disadvantages :

1. On the create, what form should we take? => You'll get the "Discard/Save changes"-screen if the form wants to change automatically...
2. It's unsupported

I think that the above error occures, because we want to open the same "Javascripts"-webresources  several times while switching from form.

Does anyone of you have the correct way of doing a dynamic form switch?